# Can't click install button in APK file installation

Tags: java, android, apk

I develop A Messenger Personal I Have a problem with installation `Apk` File
first click .`apk` File For install when get permissions Key Install Disabled
After refresh Screen mobile (use Key home) Install key enable
Please For better understanding see Screen Shots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have any apps with "Display over other apps" permission?

Comment: yes. I have some apps with permission "draw over other apps"

Comment: Android has "protection" that disables install button if it detects overlay. In Android 7 or so, they added popup to notifiy you and in Android 8 it should automatically disable them. So if you want to install the app, you first need to disable those apps (force close or disabling the overlay should be enough)

Comment: i tested android 7 but don't this problem just in android 6 have problem. so i disabled permissions for android 6 again have this problem

Comment: It can be caused by any app that overlays the screen (You might not even notice it does that). I can see some faint icons in notification bar, if those are foreground services, check those for overlay permissions.